# Parse Irregular JSON format in android

Tags: android, json

Hello friends i have following `JSON foramt`

```
{
  "Communities": [],
  "RateLog": { "83": 5,"84": 4, "85": 5,"92": 5,"93": 4,"94": 5,"95": 5,"97": 5,"99": 4,"100": 5,"102": 5,"103": 5,"104": 5,"105": 5,"106": 5,"108": 4,"109": 4,"110": 4,"111": 5,"112": 4,"113": 4,"114": 4,"115": 5,"116": 5,"117": 5,"118": 4,"119": 5, "120": 5,"121": 4,"122": 5,"123": 4,"124": 4,"125": 4,"126": 5, "142": 5,"1150": 4, "1151": 4,"1152": 4, "1153": 4,"1154": 4, "1155": 4,"1156": 4, "1158": 5}
}
```

so how can i parse it any idea?

Comment: are you sure this is your full JSON data? It is not a valid one.Check in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Post your whole `JSON` here. The `JSON`data you've posted is not valid. Please check it once.

Comment: @SpringBreaker Now check  my full json formate

Comment: @T-Rush Check my json format

Comment: With your edit, what's irregular about the JSON?

Comment: @Sardor is correct, you should follow the pattern as he suggested. this JSON looks bad in this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it into legal JSON by enclosing it in braces. So if you have the string:

```
var badJSON = '"RateLog" : { "1156": 4, ... }';
```

You can do this:

```
var goodJSON = '{' + badJSON + '}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(goodJSON);
```

EDIT: The above answer was before your edit. With the new format, the string is valid JSON, so simply call `JSON.parse()` and pass the string to get the corresponding object structure.

Answer (score 0):

You must improve your json format like this :

```
"RateLog":[
{
     id1:1156
     id2:4
{
     id1:1155
     id2:4
}
{
     id1:1155
     id2:4
}
..]
```

Comment: Exactly! JSON is for exchanging data in a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's Gson library to parse your response.

Using POJO class

```
String jsonString = "Your JSON string";

Pojo pojo = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Pojo.class);

class Pojo {
    ArrayList<String> Communities;
    HashMap<String, Integer> RateLog;

    //Setters and Getters   
}
```

Without using POGO class

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String jsonString = "Your JSON string";

JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();

HashMap<String, Integer> RateLog = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("RateLog").toString(), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Integer>>(){}.getType());
```

You can iterate through RateLog HashMap to get key, value pairs.

Comment: what about TypeToken class ?

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya TypeToken class will be present in Gson library.   [TypeToken](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)

Comment: :When i paste line `HashMap<String, Integer> RateLog = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("RateLog").toString(), TypeToken<HashMap<String, Integer>>(){}.getType());` it gave me error like TypeToken cannot be resolved to a variable create local variable,,
i use google-gson-2.2.4 jar for that

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya Find my updated answer, missed new before TypeToken

Comment: Use import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken; for TypeToken class

Answer (score 0):

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("Communities");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
//          do stuff
        }

        JSONObject rateJson = json.getJSONObject("RateLog");

        rateJson.getInt("83"); //Will return 5
        .
        .
    .
```

for more got through this tutorial

http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/